# Allow addVpc with different region in existing private hosted zone

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-route53

I stucked in addVpc from fromLookup

```
region : us-east-1
} else{
  privatehostedZone = route53.HostedZone.fromLookup(
    this, 'privatehostedZone ', {
    domainName: domainName,
    privateZone: true,
  });
  privatehostedZone.addVpc(vpc)
}
```

Is there any ways to addvpc into existing private hosted zone by cdk

Comment: No, imported resources cannot be modified. What do you mean by "different region", though?